# Do WordPress plugins connect to the WP database even when disabled?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I had a situation where a wordpress site stopped responding, showing a database connection error. I was unable to connect to phpMyAdmin as well, it was showing that there were too many open connections to the database. Working with the host provider tech support, i was told that i should delete the plugins from the site, as they were the culprit.

Now, i know that you can disable the plugins by renaming the plugin folder, but the tech support insisted i delete them, as they claimed that even when i do disable them using that method, the plugins still make connections to the database.

Is this really the case, as it does not make sense to me - you disable the plugin, and it is not active, so it should do no work, let alone connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** possible that a deactivated Plugin in WordPress is still interacting with the database. However, this would not be a best practice, it's probably a violation of [WordPress' Plugin Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/), and it's definitely not common.

To the best of my knowledge, the reason a developer would do this is probably because they don't understand [WordPress' functions for interacting with the database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) (also see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Saving_Plugin_Data_to_the_Database), so they use the vanilla PHP methods they're familiar with. It could also be malicious activity by the developer or someone who has compromised their code.

Furthermore, unfortunately it's very common for Plugins to add things to the database, and files to the WordPress install that are not removed when the Plugin is deactivated and, in some cases, even when the Plugin has been deleted.

It's acceptable for them to leave files and database meta if they inform you and give you the option to delete it at some point prior to deactivation, and definitely by the time of deleting.

Comment: Hi Spencer, so what you are saying is that, if a plugin has a query somewhere in its code, that query will be run even if the plugin is not activated? Would this be the case in a situation where, for example, i just copy a plugin into the plugins folder, but never actually activate it from WordPress backend?

Comment: Hi @Hrastovnik, I am saying that is possible, but also that it's uncommon, and probably against WordPress' policies, in fact I'll say it is but I'm just not certain where the citation is on that exactly.

Any time you copy files onto your server it's possible they run something, including connecting to and modifying a database. They can also cause a chain reaction of events. But for something like that to happen with notifying you in advance is almost certainly malicious (in my experience).

Comment: For further clarification, if it's a PHP file I can't think of any way it could be run apart from being activated unless you access the file from the browser. Which causes it to be executed.

So if you're worried that this is happening all over the place. I'd say that's not necessary. If that's not comforting then I'd recommend WPScan, WangGuard (apparently about to be discontinued) and WordFence as great security Plugins that help you scan files for vulnerabilities and malicious activity like we're talking about.